# Passenger and multiple instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Our production server has a pool size of 9, but Passenger for some reason spawn more than one pool of 9 instances!

> It appears that multiple Passenger instances are running. Please select a
>   specific one by running:
>
> passenger-status
>
> The following Passenger instances are running:
>    PID: 13281
>    PID: 31592

Of course, this kills our server a bit, since we really want to have just 9 instances (max) up. Any idea why this happens?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: just realized that when this happens, PassengerLoggingAgent gets hung at 100% CPU...

Comment: What's the `PassengerMaxPoolSize` setting in your `httpd.conf`?

Comment: 40. But for the vhost in question, only 9. The vhost one takes precendence, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Passenger documentation:

> 5.11.1. `PassengerMaxPoolSize <integer>`
>
> [...]
>
> This option may only occur once, in the global server configuration. The default value is 6.

This means you cannot use `PassengerMaxPoolSize` inside a vhost. Inside a vhost, you can use the `PassengerMinInstances` option to ensure that no single application takes up all the instances, or you may specify `PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp` on a global level to define the maximum number of instances per app.

For details, look at the [Passenger documentation](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_resource_control_and_optimization_options).